# What do rocket spaces do on Highway Rollers?

Tags: wii-party-u

On the Highway Rollers board in *Wii Party U*, there is a section of spaces with rocket icons. Landing on a rocket space launches the player forward an unspecified number of spaces.

How far ahead do the rocket spaces send you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Wii Party Wiki](http://wiiparty.wikia.com/wiki/Highway_Rollers):

> **Rocket Space**
>
> The player flies ahead to square 190 by means of a rocket.